# PHP code injection using GET and echo

Tags: php, injection

I have found a piece of this code in a web application (simplified):

```
<?php $password="very-secret-password"; $param = $_GET["param"]; ?>
<html> ...
Param: <?php echo $param; ?>
... </html>
```

I know that this is like a call to XSS, but I would like to know if attacker can run his own PHP code here. By this, I mean something like displaying the password - `page.php?param=; ?><?php echo $password; ?>`, but specifically this did not work.

Googling and OWASP cheat sheets provided no information to this specific problem.

So, can attacker run his own *PHP* code here or it is not possible? If yes, how?
(PHP v5.6)

Comment: @drewbenn - Actually, it is called `$search` in the web app. However, it should not matter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it's not possible to inject serverside code just via echoing CGI parameters. But as you say, it allows for a reflected XSS attack.

On the other hand, it's possible there may be other vulnerabilities in the code you did *not* include in your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you just echo the parameter, then the attacker can't inject any PHP code. But you make an XSS attack possible.

But if you `eval($_GET["param"])`, or eval any other code where you use one of the GET or POST parameters, then it is possible to inject PHP code.